# Error loading SQLite to Python

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I'm trying to use SQLite with python and I'm going over examples from the python website. One example is to build a shell for SQLite:
[py](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#module-functions-and-constants)

This is the beginning of the script

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.isolation_level = None
cur = con.cursor()
```

I'm loading the file from a text editor, and I'm confused by the error that I get when I import the file.

```
>>>import SQLoad
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "SQLoad.py", line 1, in <module>
  c = conn.cursor()
NameError: name 'conn' is not defined
```

I'm confused because 'conn' isn't being defined in what I'm uploading. Is it something that has to be defined?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm loading the file from a text editor"?

Comment: You're right, that isn't clear. I just meant that I have the file saved with the code for making the shell on it that I'm loading into python.

Comment: What is the first line in SQLoad.py?

Answer (score 2):

Your first code block shows that the connection variable is named `con`.

The error message shows that you have written that variable as `conn`, and that this is in the first line of `SQLoad.py`, where the connection cannot have been opened yet.

Your first code block looks correct, but it is not what is actually stored in `SQLoad.py`.